# Git status on modeline to indicate if behind remote?

Tags: git, mode-line, vc, vc-mode

Can I get Emacs to indicate on the mode-line whether a push is needed, i.e. whether the repo is out of sync with origin?

I've already got it telling me if a commit is needed using `vc-status`, but that doesn't indicate whether the most recent commit locally has been pushed to origin.

(I've got something similar going on with my oh-my-zsh prompt via ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_AHEAD_REMOTE, and I'd love to duplicate that within Emacs.)